# how to split hexadecimal address into multiple fields using tcl

Tags: tcl

I am trying to split 32 bit hexadecimal address into multiple fields using tcl and then display each field and later assign few fields to another variable. I tried below but I wasn't successful. Can you pls help me in this regard.

```
//pseudo code that I want to achieve  
field1 = addr_in[31:30]  
field2 = addr_in[29:14]  
field3 = addr_in[13:11]  ##field 3 value
field4 = addr_in[10:1]  
field5 = addr_in[0]

addr_out = {field3, field2, field4}  
print field1,field2,...field5 and addr_out
...
```

I tried list lassign but later realized that string range is the best one to use.

```
    ## actual code below
    #! /usr/bin/tclsh

    set addr  "abcd1234"  ## assigning a value to addr
    puts $addr

    set field1 [string range $addr 0 1]  ## this sets field1 as ab. 

    set field2 [string range $addr 18 20]  ## doesn't print anything
    puts $field2

    set field3 [string range $addr 2 17]
    puts $field3

    set field4 [string range $addr 21  end-1]
    puts $field4

    set field5 [string index $addr end]
    puts $field5

    set addr_out [concat $field3 $field2 $field4]
    puts $addr_out

    exit 0
    ### end of the code
```

However realized that field1 variable will only print "ab" instead of 
addr_in[31:30] bits and also field2, field3 cannot be displayed as their range is out of bounds, so I tried using binary format H* $field1 to convert the $addr into binary , then get it high to low order and then get each field value but wasn't able to get it.

Tried below as well:

```
   set field1 [string range $addr 0 1]  
   puts $field1 [binary format H* $addr field1]
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

To extract bits, we want to first convert the hexadecimal number to a bit string; we can do this with `scan` and `format`. (Mnemonic: `%x` is for handling a he**x** value, `%b` is for handling a **b**inary value.)

```
set bits [format "%032b" [scan $addr "%x"]]
```

Then we can use `string range` on that (bearing in mind that you've effectively got a big-endian value at this point):

```
set field1 [string range $bits 30 31]
```

If you want to convert that to a decimal, `scan` again:

```
set field1value [scan $field1 "%b"]
```

We can also extract multiple fields at once, converting to decimal as we go:

```
scan $bits "%1b%10b%3b%16b%2b" field5 field4 field3 field2 field1
```

(Use `s` instead of `b` to get the bit string pieces themselves.)

---

If you're using an older version of Tcl, you might need to use `binary format` and `binary scan`. I find them harder to use than plain `format` and `scan`, but you might disagree. For example, to convert the address to a bit string…

```
binary scan [binary format "H*" $addr] "Bu*" bits
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Donal. I shall try it out.

Comment: The switch to `%032b` in my edit was suggested out-of-band by Schelte Bron. Many thanks!